# image attachments with freemarker template

Tags: image, freemarker, email-attachments

I am trying to send an image attachment in email using freemarker template.

I tried using the base64 option in img tag like so:

```
"img src="data:image/png;base64," + imgDataAsBase64 "
```

However, the email service provider does not support it.
Using the URI approach is not an option. I also saw the "CID" option. 
But not able to find much documentation around it with regards to freemarker.

I would appreciate any help in this regards.

Comment: FreeMarker is on one lower level than that (multipart messages and thus CID-s), so you should check the documentation of the thing that uses FreeMarker for generating the e-mails.

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit please?  the way things work is we generate data on on fly feed it to freemarker template and the output is sent to an email end point. are you saying this approach will not work with CID?

Comment: An e-mail has different parts, like the headers (subject, recipients, etc.), then generally the main content is also from multiple parts with different MIME types and content dispositions (such as parts for embedded images referred via CID, attachment documents, etc). You may use FreeMarker templates for some of those pars, but not for the whole e-mail.